# How to use JustFLAC with 24-192 HD FLAC

Tags: java, javasound, flac

Does anyone have an example of how I can play an 24-192 HD FLAC file with JustFLAC?
JustFLAC is an fork of jFLAC and is claiming it can play this types of files.

```
package org.kc7bfi.jflac.apps;

class Player {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Player decoder = new Player();
        // FLAC HDTracks 24-192
        String f = "hdflacfile.flac";

        decoder.decode(f);
```

Throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 192000.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
```

I have tried a lot of files.

I'm on WIN8 and Java6.

JustFLAC or similar "small" packages is what I need information about.

Comment: If JustFLAC not a must, so try to use vlcj (Java bindings for the vlc)

Comment: Thanks for the information about vlcj. It was new to me. But JustFLAC or similar packages is "a must".

Comment: I'm curious if anyone has a clue...

Comment: `SourceDataLine` is an output device. This is saying that the device does not support  24-192.

Comment: If I remember correctly on my Mac Java 6 did not support 24 bit output, this was changed in Java 7 - so you may get further with Java 7 or 8.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that the JustFLAC code is saying that the audio format of the FLAC file is 'PCM_SIGNED 192000.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian' (which looks correct).

The player code will then be asking the output device for a `SourceDataLine` which matches this format so that it can write the decoded data to the line. However the output device is throwing an exception saying that it does not support this format.

This may be because the actual device does not support this format or it may be that the Java Sound API does not support it. Certainly on the Mac version of Java 6 the Java Sound API did not support 24 bit output, this was changed in Java 7 (and 8). Testing on my Mac with Java 8 a 24 bit 192Khz file plays OK.

Comment: Thanks Greg for you commented! I have now tried on Windows 7 and Java 7. Same problem as before. Guess the problem is Java under Windows. I have not had the opportunity to test in Java 8, yet.
Maybe JustFLAC only works for Linux and OSX when it comes to 24-bit audio.

Comment: The issue isn't really with JustFLAC it is with the Java Sound output device (or possibly the Windows device audio device driver).